# How can I create URL Alias for Drupal by pattern matching

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Originally I have urls like www.astral.com/user/1. I was able to convert it to www.astral.com/casuername by patterns match using [user:cas] where casuername comes from [user:cas]

However, I also have www.astral.com/user/1/publications which I want to convert to www.astral.com/user/1/publications to www.astral.com/casuername/publications.

Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search, I found that, my objective can be achieved using subpath auto module obtained from https://www.drupal.org/project/subpathauto

Answer (score 0):

Use pathauto module
https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto
Create the pattern for the urls

Comment: Pathauto cannot alias everything within the subpages. However, no worries, I found that subpathauto can do that.